# How to get registered customer details in order success page(success.phtml) in M2.2?

Tags: magento2, customer, register, order-success-page

I am using Magento 2.2. I want to display customer name, address line 1, adrdress line 2, city, phone, email in order success page.

This is my code in `success.phtml`:

```
    <?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getContinueUrl() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

$lid = $this->getOrderId();
echo  "Order ID:".$lid."<br/>";

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lid);


$totall = $order->getGrandTotal();
echo "Order Total:".$totall."<br/>";

$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

if ($shippingAddress)
{
    $telephone_tmp  = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
    $customer_email = $shippingAddress->getEmail();
    $postal         = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
    $city           = $shippingAddress->getCity();
    $address_tmp    = $shippingAddress->getData('street');
}

/* getting Guest Account Details */
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
    $firstname      = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname       = $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    $customer_name  = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
    $telephone_tmp  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    $customer_email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
    $postal         = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $city           = $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
    $address_tmp    = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
    echo $customer_name."<-------- new customer";
}
/* getting Register Account Details */
else {
    $customer  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    //else, they're a normal registered user.
    $firstname = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname  = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    echo $customer_name = $firstname.' '.$lastname ."<--------   exist customer";

}
$telephone = substr($telephone_tmp, 0, 10);

$space_count = (int)substr_count($address_tmp," ");
if ($space_count > 2)
{
    $address_pieces = explode(' ', $address_tmp);
    $address1       = $address_pieces[0].' '.$address_pieces[1].' '.$address_pieces[2];
    $address2       = $address_pieces[3].' '.$address_pieces[4];
}
else
{
    $address1 = $address_tmp;
}

echo "Name:".$customer_name."<br/>"; 

echo "Telephone No:".$telephone."<br/>"; 

echo "Email:".$customer_email."<br/>"; 

echo "postcode".$postal."<br/>"; 

echo "city".$city."<br/>"; 

echo "address1".$address1."<br/>";

echo "address2".$address2."<br/>";
```

Please help to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($block->getOrderId()); // pass orderId
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
    $firstname      = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname       = $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    $customer_name  = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
    $telephone_tmp  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    $customer_email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
    $postal         = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $city           = $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
    $address_tmp    = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
    echo $customer_name."<-------- new customer";
}
/* getting Register Account Details */
else {
    $customer  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    //else, they're a normal registered user.
    $firstname = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname  = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    echo $customer_name = $firstname.' '.$lastname ."<--------   exist customer";
}
```

Working code.

Comment: Thank you. But it shows error " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in ...."

Comment: check my updated answer @TamilSelvan

Comment: Still got error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFirstname() on boolean in. Please check my updated code @Chander Shekhar

Comment: I just removed getDefaultBillingAddress(), now its working.... @Chander Shekar.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below code for registered and guest customers...

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
 $order         = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());

 $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

working code try to use it.

if this is helpful for you please give kudos.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: hi @Rohit, using Objectmanager directly is not recommended.

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar , you can use object manager directly in design files

Comment: yes @Rohit, we can use but not recommended, :)

Answer (score 2):

For customer Information in order after order placed successfully you need to create Observer.

event :

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="magecomp_place_order_after" instance="Magecomp\Sms\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
</event>
```

Create php file in Observer in your module 
Observer/Orderplaceafter.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
      protected $objectManager;
      public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
   )
   {
       $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
   }
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
        $order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
        $order = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id[0]);
        $customerid = $order->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerid);
         $customerName = $customer->getCustomerName()    
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just removed getDefaultBillingAddress(), now its working....